# Can't serve large data using the Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, servlets, websphere-7

I wrote the simplest Servlet possible for serving a stream of data (in the test case it's a 14GB text file) to the client:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    resp.setContentLength(-1);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        int unitsTransferred = -1;
        byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
        is = new FileInputStream("D:/largetext2.txt");
        while ((unitsTransferred = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            os.write(buf, 0, unitsTransferred);
            //os.flush();
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            resp.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So you just make a simple get request. I tried making GET request to this servlet from a java client using `URLConnection` and from Chrome browser. Both cases manage to download randomly from 1 MB to 90 MB then the downloading stalls, while, even after the client has stalled, the Private Bytes of the `java.exe` process of the WAS server keeps going up (from 300 MB to 950 MB) then the server spits out the following stack trace:

```
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
at  com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:106)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:569)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:374)
at si.test.kryo.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (2), reason: RC: 64  The specified network name is no longer available.

```
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:213)
... 3 more
```

Java client just stays blocked in a read call, while Chrome keeps the download alive, oblivious to the fact that server aborted the whole thing. So either there's some weird timeout going on or there's a problem with the IBM servlet container.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Tried it with 100 MB file. Download runs fast up to 26MB then it stalls, memory consumption goes up 100 MB. The servlet code finishes (checked with `sysout` printout).

Comment: My best guess seems to be a deadlock issue or a `wait/notify` threading issue that occurs once the response queue in the web container gets full. Business as usual for IBM.

Comment: Could also be a Windows issue (the reason code is specific to Windows). Do you have the same issue on another platform?

Comment: I believe there is a 32-bit limit implied by the servlet specification, and WebSphere Application Server does not implement any extensions to allow 64-bit. Even so, there should not be a hang with transfers less than that, so I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?